# react-I18next loading translation file from src folder

Tags: react-i18next

is it possible to load translation file from src folder when using react-i18next ?

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)// detect user language  
  .use(LanguageDetector)// pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(HttpApi) //handle the path of data from translation.json file
  .use(initReactI18next) // init i18next 
  .init({
    supportedLngs : ['fr', 'en'], //langauges supported  in the app
    fallbackLng: 'fr', //default language
    ns:['navBar', 'home'],  //file to load for different content
    defaultNS : 'home', //defualt file to load
    fallbackNS: 'navBar', 
    detection : {
      order: ['cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'path', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'], //where user's language is cached
    },
    backend: {
      **loadPath: '/assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'** //where to find file.json
    }
  });
```